# Tips for optimizing identification of `k` consecutive equal characters

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question:

> An operation consists of selecting `k` consecutive equal characters and removing them.  This operation is to be performed as long as possible.  Return the final word after all the operations have been performed.  For e.g., for `abbcccb` and `k`=`3`, the output should be `a`.

The code that I could come up with is as follows:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;

string helper(string& s, int k) {
    if(s.size()<k) return s;
    
    string str;
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        char currChar=s[i];
        int j=i+1, count=0;
        while(j<s.size() && count<=k && s[j]==currChar) {
            j++;
            count++;
        }

        if(j-i==k) {
            for(int k=0; k<i; k++) str.push_back(s[k]);
            for(int k=j; k<s.size(); k++) str.push_back(s[k]);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(str.empty()) return s;
    return helper(str, k);
}

int main() {
    // string s="abbcccb";
    // string s="abcdef";
    // string s="baac";
    string s="aba";
    cout<<helper(s, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Working code [here](https://ideone.com/6eADBS).

However, I think there is a possible way to optimize the code further, especially the part where I determine if `k` consecutive characters are equal.

Could someone please provide few pointers/ideas/solution?

Thanks.

Comment: you should care primarily for correctness. Currently your code results in `aa` when the input is `aaaa` but it should also remove the second `aa`

Comment: you didn't get my point. This is premature optimization. It is meaningless to optimize code that does not produce correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard problem that can be solved using stack in O(n) time. Full explanation is already given on this site. Please refer this [Reduce the string by removing K consecutive identical characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-the-string-by-removing-k-consecutive-identical-characters/)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please add sufficient explanation to the answer to make it self-contained.